# PHP run python script every n seconds

Tags: php, python, command-line, cron, nohup

I have a python script that I'd like to run every n seconds. I want to be able to start the script with a PHP page. I'd like it to run in the background so that I can visit my page, hit 'go', leave the page, come back in a few hours, and stop the whole thing.

I'm trying to build a web interface for capturing a screenshot from a webcam every n seconds so that I can compile the image sequence into a time lapse video later.

The command I'm trying to use is:

```
nohup watch -n20 python imgDownload.py &
```

This usually works when I enter it directly into the command line, but in PHP when I do

```
$cmd = 'nohup watch -n20 python imgDownload.py &';
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

or

```
exec($cmd, $output);
```

or even

```
$cmd = 'nohup watch -n20 python ' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/imgDownload.py &';
```

it doesn't work.

I know that shell_exec() works because I can successfully run the following:

```
echo shell_exec("echo 'hi, there'");
```

it puts 'hi, there' on the page, like it should.

Any ideas why it wouldn't work? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what error's do you get?

Comment: No errors. When the page loads it either hangs, or when I do "exec() or die('died')" it chooses to die.

Comment: Did you verify that the command shell_exec() was enabled ?

Comment: given that it hanging it could be waiting for the program to finish, theres a number of options discussed in the php manual to solve this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @AlanChavez shell_exec() works for more simple commands. See the edit I just made.

Comment: @Justin Is apache user allowed to execute nohup? have you tried other commands?  like `echo shell_exec(" touch /usr/bin/foobartest ");`

Answer (score 0):

use exec and redirect the output to /dev/null, this will cause php to not wait on the command to finish:

```
$cmd = 'nohup watch -n20 python imgDownload.py &';
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```